# controls in ReacitveForm dowsn't work good when navigate in pages

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, pagination, controls

I have a problem with the controller when I go to the next page. On the front page the controller works very well, when I go to the second page, the same values are repeated.Please look my  [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbzrma?file=app/app.component.html)

How to solve this problem, any idea please?

Thanks

Comment: Really recommend you to use formarray when using ngFor for formgroups: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: Can you try something in my demo please?!